# Crossword, but math!

Tags: mathematics, crosswords

This kind of puzzle is from my mom's puzzle magazines. There it is called Figure Logic. It is essentially a crossword, but with math. In crosswords, all words must be real words. In Figure Logic, **no numbers can start with 0**. (EDIT) Also, all digits 0-9 appear.

[image]

XA/D means "X Across/Down". So 1 Across is half of 5 Down. Sorry about this!

Clues

```
Across
1. 5 down / 2
4. One digit is twice the other
6. 15 down + 20
8. Even
9. One digit is the sum of the others
11. Contains the only occurrence of a digit
13. Odd
14. Divisible by 1D
16. Divisible by 3
17. 5 x 10 down + 5
20. Consecutive digits in some order
21. Consecutive digits in some order

Down
1. Not prime
2. Non-consecutive digits
3. All digits are even
4. A perfect number - 2D
5. Divisible by 11
7. 13 across + 130
10. Living people were born this year
12. 15 down + 13 across
15. 1 across x 20 across
16. Can be written as a factorial
18. 4 across + 8 across
19. Prime
```

There is a unique solution which can be found without guessing. If you're confused about any definitions, please Google, or comment and I can explain. Also, calculators are allowed and likely required for some of the big numbers.

Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how 17A is possible - are you sure that clue is correct?

Comment: Also, how is there a unique solution when the only information we get about the top middle square is that it's even? 3D can only give us four options for that cell, and no other clue references that cell.

Comment: I agree with both points raised by @Deusovi so far

Comment: I'm also hitting a contradiction trying to solve without 17A at all...

Comment: When you say some thing like "5D" do you mean multiplication (5 * D) or concatenation (50 + D). Also im guessing the variables remain constant throughout the puzzle?

Comment: @Deusovi hey, i think maybe it is concatenation not multiplication, and that would address the problems you asked. I put a comment requesting @ bobble to confirm.

Comment: @Ankit That wouldn't make sense. 5D should refer to clue 5-Down. (And similarly, 13A should refer to clue 13-Across.) These puzzles normally have these types of cross-references; it would be impossible to solve without them. And that still doesn't address clue 3D.

Comment: @Ankit Even if it's concatenation, I don't think it works.  The number (at least with the digit I found must start it) is too big.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realize this was confusing - 5D means "5 Down", 1A means "1 Across". I'll edit that in.

Comment: For clue 17A instead of 5D I think it should have said 10D, that would make it work. As for 3D, there is a technique I’ve read about that if a guess is presented that would lead to multiple solutions then that guess is considered “wrong”. Clue 11A says it contains the only occurrence of a digit, right now I have 2 possibilities for that digit - one even and one odd; however, if I chose the odd digit, then for that clue to be true the left over even digit will have to go to 3D. I think that’s the intended solution.

Comment: Ahhh yes 17A is 10D, can't see how I missed that. So sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was fun, thanks for posting it - hopefully my answer is correct!

> [image]

Explanation:

> **16D = 24** since this is the only 2-digit number that can be written as a factorial, and **4D = 8xxx** since 8128 is the only perfect number that is 4 digits, and since 2D is a two-digit number, the difference cannot be less than 8000.
>
>  Therefore: **4A = 84**, **5D = 44**, and **1A = 22**.
>
>  Now if we look at 4D again, we can see that 8128 - 2D is between 8128 - 28 = 8100, and 8128 - 20 = 8108. Note that 4D ≠ 8128 - 29 = 8099 as this would result in 8A starting with the digit 0. So **4D = 810x** which means that **8A = 14**.
>
>  Therefore: **18D = 98**. Also since 17A is a multiple of 5, it must end in the digit 5 or 0. Since 19D cannot start with the digit 0, it must start with the digit 5. Since 21A starts with an 8, it must be 87 or 89, but combining this with 19A since 59 is prime but 57 is not we have **19D = 59**, and **21A = 89**.
>
>  This next step is important! We have that **17A = xx95**, so 5 x 10D = xx90, a 4-digit number ending in 90. Since multiplying by 5 is the same as multiplying by 10 and dividing by 2, 10D / 2 must end in the digit 9, meaning that 10D ends in the digit 8. So we have **10D = xxx8** but since 10D is a year living people were born in, 2018 and 2008 won't work since this would result in 13A starting with the digit 0. Therefore, 10D is a year in the 1900s, or **10D = 19x8**. Using a calculator to check all of the possibilities for the third digit of 10D such that 17A = 5 x 10D + 5, we determine that **10D = 1978**, and **17A = 9895**.
>
>  Now we see that 20A is either 43 or 45, meaning that **15D** is either 22 x 43 = 946, or 22 x 45 = 990. Using what we know about 17A, we can see **15D = 990** and thus **20A = 45**.
>
>  Therefore: **6A = 1010**, **1D = 21**, **2D = 20**, **4D = 8108**.
>
>  Since 12D = 15D + 13A = 990 + 98x, the last digit of 13A is 5, making **13A = 985**. Then **12D = 1975** and **7D = 1115**. It also checks out that 1D = 21 is a multiple of **14A = 9597** (when I originally solved this problem, I was missing information for 1D and 14A, so I had to verify that 9x97 = 9597 was the *only* number of this form that was a multiple of a number in the twenties since I had only the first digit of 1D - oh well!).
>
>  Now since 9A = 1x10, in order for one digit to be the sum of the others, the last remaining digit is 2, making **9A = 1210**. The only two remaining digits that haven't been used are 6 and 3. Since 3D = x02 is composed of all even numbers, we get **3D = 602**, and 11D = x11 must be **11D = 311** satisfying the only occurrence of the digit 3.

Comment: Happy someone liked it! Again, sorry for the clue problems.

Comment: No worries! I hope there are more cool variations on crosswords like this one :)

Comment: Can you post your explanation, too, Derek?

Comment: No problem, I just posted it!